# What Stack Exchange community should I use to post my question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Generally I mostly use the Spanish Language and the Stack Overflow (for programming questions) communities. However my question isn't about code but about *a website's cost*.

For example, a title such as,

> Why are the operation cost of a some websites so expensive?

I fear that asking a question with a title such as the above will be closed as off topic in the Stack Overflow community.

I have checked the [All Sites - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) but couldn't find a suitable community.

Comment: If there isn't any community for which your question is suitable, then don't post it on any of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question is extremely broad, and therefore does not sound like it would be suitable for any of the Stack Exchange sites. A detailed explanation of the cost factors behind hosting a website is beyond the scope of an answer on Stack Exchange sites.

If you can narrow the scope down *significantly*, to where you are asking a specific question about the cost of hosting a website, you might be able to ask on [Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

From their [Help Center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast webmasters focused on how to operate websites. Questions here are commonly about
>
> - search engine optimization (SEO)
> - domains
> - web-hosting
> - internet marketing
>
> This site is for anything that relates to owning, running, or administering your own website.

Do note the phrasing ***"your own website"***. It's a Q&A site for webmasters, not a general Q&A site for all websites on the Internet.

If you have a specific question about using a particular popular web applications, like Gmail or Facebook, you can get help on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but the technical details of hosting such a website would be off-topic there. This Q&A site is designed for *users* of those web applications.